# How do I eradicate Mint

Tags: mint, invasive

I have tried googling with no real answers without destroying the soil. I searched this forum and found [this posting](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4172/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mint) answered, but the answer suggests to mow the mint which is not an option for me.

I had bought this house where it looks like the previous owners planted a bunch of plants including mint into this raised bed that is part of 2 beds that step up a hill side (bottom bed in [this picture](http://photos1.zillow.com/p_f/IS171h5v1kp0xib.jpg) from 2007). We tilled it about 2 years ago, got rid of all the mint roots we could find, and planted a bunch of vegetables.

After that year we left the bed to nature. This year we tilled the bed again, getting rid of all the mint roots we could find, and planted vegetables in April. Today I went to dig some holes to add additional vegetables and found a ton of mint roots everywhere.

How do I eradicate the mint from this bed without damaging the soil?

Comment: see also http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/4172/754

Comment: @Kate Gregory I did see that and cited it in my question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you've got veggies growing in the plot right now? I think then for this season, hand-pulling the mint is your best option. Once the veggies are out, I'd cover the area in sheets of plastic (either black or clear) And secure the edges so it is flat against the ground. It will take several months to kill the mint, but eventually it will be smothered.

Comment: Thanks! I will see about doing this after the vegetables are done

Answer (score 3):

In the fall hand pull as much as you can. Every little piece of root grows new plants so tilling just makes thousands of babies. Then mulch with plastic but be aware that if there are any pieces of root left underneath they may spread and grow outside the plastic. I have one type of fuzzy mint that has roots running 3-5 feet under everything in the garden. Remove any bits that grow outside the plastic.