# Controlling Coriander/Cilantro 

Tags: herbs, bolting, cilantro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you discourage cilantro from bolting too quickly?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/90/how-do-you-discourage-cilantro-from-bolting-too-quickly)

I have a Coriander plant that I think is [bolting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolting_%28horticulture%29). It started flowering and got quite tall.Most of the standard coriander leaves have gone, and have been replaced by Fennel-like leaves.

I assume I can't cook with these? Is there anything I can do to make it produce the standard type leaves?

Comment: Cilantro is the Spanish-American name for Coriander. The site is using US tags - so I've added the existing cilantro tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've had a lot of problems with cilantro bolting. I understand the leaves lose their flavor, as well as looking a bit odd. We've let it go to seed, and let it seed itself (with Texas weather that means the late spring/summer seed becomes the autumn crop).

You could also collect coriander seed - this is a herb/spice as well.

Cilantro/coriander bolting is a response to heat. It is a defense against dying - much better to produce new seed and to pass the genes on to the next generation. So you choices are to let it go to seed and accept there's a limited growing season;  or to find a cooler place for it.